# How to load lines from a file into variables that can be either strings, floats, or ints?

Tags: python

I tried using `int()` and `str()` but it gave me an `ValueError`. I'm making a RPG where you can save and load your data using text files, and i want it to take data from a previous game (in a text file, already achieved) and set the variables from specific line numbers, so you get your previous data.

My code is:

```
f = open(name+".txt",'r')
enter = f.readline()
y = enter[0]
hp = enter[1]
coins = enter[2]
status = enter[3]
y2 = enter[4]
y3 = enter[5]
energy = enter[6]
stamina = enter[7]
item1 = enter[8]
item2 = enter[9]
item3 = enter[10]
equipped = enter[11]
firstime = enter[12]
armorpoint1 = enter[13]
armorpoint2 = enter[14]
armorpoints = enter[15]
upgradepoint1 = enter[16]
upgradepoint2 = enter[17]
firstime3 = enter[18]
firstime4 = enter[19]
part2 = enter[20]
receptionist = enter[21]
unlocklist = enter[22]
armorlist = enter[23]
heal1 = enter[24]
heal2 = enter[25]
heal3 = enter[26]
unlocked = enter[27]
unlocked2 = enter[28]
f.close()
```

(I didn't put in global because it would be too long.)
When I run this, I get an error saying the index is out of range. The code is on https://repl.it/@HamsterCoding/Screen-Testing#screen.py if you want to see it better.

Comment: You read *one line* from the file, and tried to store its first 29 *individual characters* into your variables (apparently the first line was shorter than that).  `.readlines()` (with an `s`) would give you a list whose elements are the lines of your file - but note that each will end with a newline character.

Comment: don't use numbered locations of variables, use some kind of key-value pairs, will make your life a lot easier when you need to delete/add/modify the settings

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have the following txt-file:

```
1
word
2.5
```

The first issue you face is that the default type of the value from the text file is going to be string. Therefore, a classification of the content of the file would help you. The following piece of code will achieve this:

```
f = open('1.txt', 'r')
val_int = []
val_float = []
val_str = []
for i, line in enumerate(f):
    try:
        val = float(line)
        if val.is_integer():
            val_int.append((i,int(val)))
        else:
            val_float.append((i,val))
    except:
        val_str.append((i,line.replace('\n','')))
f.close()
print(val_int) # OUTCOME: [(0, 1)]
print(val_float) # OUTCOME: [(2, 2.5)]
print(val_str) # OUTCOME: [(1,'word')]
```

The tuple to maintain the index of the line for future use.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an index out of bounds because readline() only reads the one line. You should use readlines() to get an array of all the lines in your text file.

**File:**

```
duck
1
c
1.2
```

**Code:**

```
f = open("duck.txt")
enter = f.readlines() # Changed from readline to readlines
y = enter[0].replace("\n", "") # .replace replaces all newlines ("\n") with empty strings
hp = enter[1].replace("\n", "")
coins = enter[2].replace("\n", "")
status = enter[3].replace("\n", "")
print(enter)
print(y)
print(int(hp)) # cast str to int
print(coins)
print(float(status)) # cast str to float
```

**Output:**

```
['duck\n', '1\n', 'c\n', '1.2']
duck
1 # int
c
1.2 # float
```